# Find value of a cell below a cell reference

Tags: excel

I have a cell containing a reference to another cell. For example, the contents of a cell would be `=timing.Y3`. I want the cell to the right of this to provide the equivalent of putting `=timing.Y4` (the cell underneath the one that was referenced). How can this be done in excel?

I have attempted to use =OFFSET(INDIRECT('cell referencing timing.y3'),0,-1) but it just says 0. It should say the value of the cell underneath timing.y3.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a little under-specified. Assuming that you're not looking for the trivial answer of setting a reference to Y5, I'll assume that you are trying to have a row of cells that references every 'Odd' cell in a different column, for example C3 has the value of Y5, D3 has the value of Y7, and so on, as shown below:

[Referencing ODD elements in a column in a continuous row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ1Qv.gif)

In order to do this, you can use a formula that converts ROWs to COLUMNS by swapping them in a 'OFFSET' formula reference. Put this formula in each cell of Row 3: `=OFFSET( $Y$3, 2*(COLUMN(C3)- COLUMN($C$3)),0)`

I hope I've interpreted your question correctly!